# How to learn the current tcp flavor in Fedora/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

How do I know which tcp flavor is used in Fedora/Ubuntu?

Comment: i prefer mint, but others like strawberry

Comment: Can you provide some more context/background?  I suspect something is being lost in the translation.

Comment: vanilla is my favorite.

Answer (score 1):

The congestion control algorithm used is set using the sysctl variable net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control, which is set to cubic or reno by default, depending on which version of the 2.6 kernel you are using.

So you can get the current tcp protocol used by typing the following command:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_allowed_congestion_control
```

Comment: If this is the answer you where looking for, then you really should update the question so it is more obvious that you wanted to know about congestion control.

Answer (score 0):

Download the kernel source and look?  Of course I don't believe that Ubuntu or Fedora or doing much different with TCP versus the official kernel

- http://www.kernel.org/
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/
- https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb